# Is there any standard or software for mapping HTTP REST requests to command line parameters?

Tags: rest

You could say the HTTP REST request is the command line of the web: it calls for a specific service and provides details about how it wants that service performed.

And indeed, many web service calls translate to creating a child process, handing it some corresponding arguments, and copying standard output back to the HTTP client. Services that do Microsoft Word to PDF conversion online, for example, probably have this workflow.

In some cases it seems redundant to define a new HTTP API when the command line utility has its own valid interface. Is there any standard defined here, or any software that helps with "*automagically*" wrapping a command line utility with HTTP REST and assisting with input validation details?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no standard way to do it. It depends on the service you are providing, the parameters you need and the result you expect. There are some *guidelines* and *good practices* to design *REST APIs* but nothing directly related to what you mentioned.

It's important to remember the REST architecture uses the [client-server model](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2) and it's *protocol independent*. However, the *most common approach* is to design it over the [HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

A REST API based on the HTTP protocol provides [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)s as a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) for your service and use the [standard HTTP methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9), allowing the service to be invoked from multiple clients that support HTTP.

In a REST API, you can provide *different resource representations*, such as JSON or XML, and the clients can request the most appropriate representation according to their needs. The API calls can be restricted per user or they can be charged for using your service.

By definition, REST applications are [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3). It means each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to be understood by the server, do not taking advantage of any stored context on the server. The session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

According to Roy Thomas Fielding, the guy who defined how REST is supposed to be, the [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) constraint induces the properties of *visibility*, *reliability*, and *scalability*:

> *Visibility* is improved because a monitoring system does not have to look beyond a single request datum in order to determine the full nature of the request. *Reliability* is improved because it eases the task of recovering from partial failures. *Scalability* is improved because not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free resources, and further simplifies implementation because the server doesn't have to manage resource usage across requests.

The [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) approach also reflects a design trade-off:

> The disadvantage is that it may decrease network performance by increasing the repetitive data (per-interaction overhead) sent in a series of requests, since that data cannot be left on the server in a shared context. In addition, placing the application state on the client-side reduces the server's control over consistent application behavior, since the application becomes dependent on the correct implementation of semantics across multiple client versions.